# How to hide Report in App without impacting Dashboard visibility?

Tags: powerbi

I loaded Power BI Report to Workspace and created Dashboard (single page data store) to store all multiply page data from Report within one Page. Now in my App I want to publish only Dashboard and not Report. However, without Report, visuals in Dashboard get invisible. Even if I add Report as content of App and make it invisible via Audience, still data in Dashboard doesn't appear. How can I hide Report without impacting visibility of Dashboard? Thank you in advance.

After adding both Report and Dashboard to Content of App, I hided Report via Audience however that triggered all visuals from Dashboard to disappear as well.... How can I hide Reprot without affecting Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to the same problem, and so far have found nothing. Apparently this is intended behaviour for some reason. (for reference: [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/How-to-add-dashboard-to-app-while-hiding-report/m-p/3057778) and some workaround that doesnt work for me [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Dashboard-Tiles-not-working-with-Power-BI-App/m-p/2758555))

The possible workaround I'm exploring:

- just don't use dashboards and add tailored reports that look like the dashboards I wanted. Downside is that I need to duplicate report content for this. Also this will leave a little arrow next to every report, which just looks sloppy.
- keep the dashboards and leave the reports visible in a group that has a whitespace as name. Downside is that users can still just click on the little arrow and see the reports. Which sucks if you don't want to share every page in the report. So if you use paginated reports, the first option would be better.

I just wish Microsoft would address this issue as it seems to have been around since they upgraded the appbuilder interface. The idea that this behaviour is 'intended' just sounds like a weak excuse to me.

Hope my suggestions above help you, and if you find a more robust solution to this problem, please do let me know.